# CakePHP form submit by link click

Tags: cakephp

onto the next question about cakePHP :)

In php, I am able to simulate a form submit by for example browsing to a url like

```
<a href="index.php?click=yes&ip=127.0.0.1">submit youre ip</a>
```

this would submit the form on index.php with the values of click being yes and ip being 127.0.0.1 without having to click a submit form.

How would I achieve the same thing in CakePHP?

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Sorry formatting cut a bit of my question description off.

Comment: never use a GET to do a POST's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to setup an index action in a controller.

An example:

If you want to add an user with the above data, you can do the following:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    function add($click, $ip) {

    $this->User->set(array('click' => $click, 'ipaddress' => $ip);
    $this->User->save();

     }

}
```

Now if you go to http://localhost/users/add/yes/127.0.0.1 it should save the data...

Comment: Perfect, thanks, now i see it like that, it was rather simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for this something like the following:

```
$('#my-link').click(function(){
  $('#my-form').submit();
});
```

EDIT: [This also seems relevant to your interests](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Posting-a-form-with-a-regular-link-td1279227.html)

Comment: Hi 8vius, Sorry because the formatting wasnt correct it actually cut a bit of my question off, I have updated this. I have also gone through and accepted answers from previous questions. Usually forget to do this after I have the answer as i get back to coding :) Thanks for the advice though

Comment: You want a purely PHP solution?

Comment: Well have you tried the solution I expressed already? Do you use jQuery in your project?

Comment: yes, your missing my question, I already use a solution like that, but what do i actually set #my-form to be in a cakephp url? eg when writing my own code #my-form would be index.php?click=yes&ip=127.0.0.1    what would it be for a cakephp valid url to perform the same action?

Comment: How are you creating your forms? When you create a form in CakePHP it already points by default to an action in your controller. By submitting it you are doing a POST to the action it points to.

Comment: I think I just understood, the URL for cakephp would be www.yoursite.com/controller/index/yes/127.0.0.1 and you controller action should something like function action($clicked, $ip)

Answer (score 0):

In Cake 2.0 you should create a link this way:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('submit your ip', array(
'controller' => 'users',
'action' => 'index',//this is not necessary since index is the default action
'?' => array('click' => 'yes', 'ip' => '127.0.0.1'))
);?>
```

and this will create:

```
<a href="/users/?click=yes&ip=127.0.0.1">submit your ip</a>
```

Then you get the data in your UsersController through $this->request->query

For better understanding look [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) and [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html).

Hope this helps.